# Date format in en.yml not being called in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, localization, internationalization

I want to format the date of `Person.created_at` (`created_at` is the default field Rails uses to monitor creation times) and show it like:

```
- @people.each do |person|
  h1= l person.created_at
```

I've created this localization in the `en.yml` file:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d -- %m"
```

I wrote in that `default: "%d -- %m"` just to test, but no changes happen. The date still displays as:

```
Sat, 27 Jul 2013 19:14:47 +0000
```

What am I missing here? I've already stopped and restarted the server to make sure the changes take.

Answer (score 0):

#created_at is a Time object (actually an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object, but it acts like a Time as far as localization is concerned). You need

```
en:
  time:
```

etc